# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, opencv, for-loop

Hi I have a list of coordinates to select certain region of interests in an image.But I am getting the error like in the heading when I pass these coordinates to the image

Here is the code :

```
coord_list =['[55:130,190:707]', '[178:280,30:387]', '[181:273,424:739]', '[181:273,424:739]']

image1 = cv2.imread(r'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\images\\Sample.jpg')
image1 = cv2.resize(image,(1000,1000))
image_roi = image1[coord_list[0]]
cv2.imshow('img',image_roi)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

*It have to be iterated from the list since I have to use the same coordinates for many images in a folder*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly slice an array with a index that is a string. You have to evaluate it first:

```
image_roi = eval('image1'+coord_list[0])
```

edit:

in response to your comment, you could for instance use `numpy` for this.
This way you can directly use it without needing to use `eval()`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

coord_list = [np.s_[55:130,190:707],np.s_[178:280,30:387],np.s_[181:273,424:739],np.s_[182:273,424:738] ]
image1 = cv2.imread('dog.jpg')
image1 = cv2.resize(image1,(1000,1000))

image_roi = image1[coord_list[0]]
cv2.imshow('img',image_roi)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: It is probably better though to not save the list of coordinates as strings

Comment: why is that @joostblack

Comment: @RahulRamesh I replied as an edit because that way I could use more characters.

Comment: I used my image for testing purposes, so you would need to change that back.